# How does animate() in jquery affect the page flow and the overflow property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, overflow

Hey guys so I just finished reading my first xhtml/css book and am now in the middle of a javascript/html one. I want to make a very simple effect but can't figure it out because I'm unfamiliar with jquery (and javascript for that matter).

So I would like an effect just like this: [kk.pcriot.com/websites.html](http://kk.pcriot.com/websites.html)

Where an image moves around but there is a sort of "mask" around it's border so its holder is fixed into place but the image moves (on mouse over). The image should snap back into its original place once the mouse cursor is not hovering over it but that seems simple enough. Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to create that mask.... It's simple enough with a static image and the `overflow:hidden` property but I think `animate()` takes the element out of the flow or something because I can't get overflow to work. Maybe it has something to do with the position property as well.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
div { width : 100px; height: 100px;
  border: thin solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  }

img { position:absolute;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
```

;}

Script:

```
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#clickme").click(function() {
   $("#book").animate({

    left: '+=150',

  } 
 });
```

body:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<image id="book" src="../Images/test.jpg"  (Newbs cant post images so I didnt use IMG)
   />
```

So... it does animate but the overflow property does not work. And when I take out the script the overflow property does work but obviously the animation doesn't!

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: According to your HTML, there would be no "overflow" for the image at all.  `overflow` property would be applied to a parent container of the `img`, and I don't see a container around the image in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the jsfiddle to move the image on hover and to clean up the CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/Q4zXd/3/

You need the image to be in a container if you want it to be bigger than the container and for a portion of it to be hidden and then move into view when you hover over the area.

The reason you need to position the container as relative is to make the interior element (img) that is positioned absolute position itself relative to the containing element, not the window.  By default, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the document flow and positioned relative to the window, not the containing element, unless the containing element is positioned relatively (absolute also works, but then that element is no longer in the document flow.)

Comment: I have to reread your explanation over and over again but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: hidden
```

does only work in your case, when the parent has a position of absolute too. Also pay attention to @Sparky672's comment. The image must be inside the div.

I've set up a demo for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4zXd/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried adding a container earlier but that didn't seem to work either.http://jsfiddle.net/YVHkP/ So the JS code flat out doesn't run at all when I add those css lines... I'm trying to play around with it right now to see what I'm missing here.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure why it won't work on jsfiddle but I got it working. Key was making the #book div relative while the container absolute. Don't ask me how it works lol. That I'm trying to figure out. http://jsfiddle.net/Srw8U/1/  Last step is to make it less jerky when you click.